# Change legend style in ggplot2 according to geom_point and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am developing a graphic with ggplot2 to show a trend. My dataframe `D` have 3 variables, `Season,variable,value`. My dataframe has the next structure (I add `dput()` version in the final part):

```
     Season variable      value
1      I1   Energy 0.01278667
2      I2   Energy 0.01260430
3      I3   Energy 0.01228117
4      I4   Energy 0.01328996
5      I5   Energy 0.01299958
6      I6   Energy 0.01201685
7      I7   Energy 0.01189642
8      I8   Energy 0.01217838
9      I9   Energy 0.01233255
10    I10   Energy 0.01232536
11    I11   Energy 0.01258488
12    I12   Energy 0.01281201
13    I13   Energy 0.01300705
14    I14   Energy 0.01240693
15    I15   Energy 0.01252280
```

Then I used next code to build my graph:

```
library(ggplot)
colors=c("red")
k <- ggplot(D, aes(x=Season, y=value,colour=variable))+ scale_color_manual(values=colors)
k <- k + geom_line(aes(group=variable),size=1.3)
k <- k + geom_point(aes(colour=variable, group=variable),size=3.8,color="white")
k <- k + geom_point(shape = 1,size = 3.8,colour = "red",pch=21)
```

And I get this result:[image]

As you can see, the line inside the graphic has white points with a red circle, but in the legend I only can get the red line, I would like to get the same style in the legend with the red line, white point and the final red circle, but I have tried with `scale_fill_manual()` and `scale_shape_manual()` without the expected result. The `dput()` version of `D` is the next:

```
D<-structure(list(Season = c("I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", 
"I7", "I8", "I9", "I10", "I11", "I12", "I13", "I14", "I15"), 
    variable = c("Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", 
    "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", 
    "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy"), value = c(0.012786665141136, 
    0.0126042983510972, 0.0122811687909691, 0.0132899632080331, 
    0.0129995810741794, 0.0120168475656266, 0.0118964227439713, 
    0.0121783793582495, 0.0123325459567189, 0.0123253641689817, 
    0.0125848787414067, 0.0128120137327422, 0.0130070542705156, 
    0.012406925298038, 0.0125228003610738)), .Names = c("Season", 
"variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than drawing two sets of points, you'll want to use shapes 21-25 to get filled shapes. This allows you to set fill and color separately. For example

```
ggplot(D, aes(x=Season, y=value, color=variable))+ 
    geom_line(aes(group=variable),size=1.3) +
    geom_point(size=3.8, shape=21, fill="white") + 
    scale_color_manual(values=colors)
```

which returns

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick and a little question if I have more than one serie with the same structure I will get filled points for all series or should I make another extra change.

Comment: That depends on what your data is like. I tried to make it so that if you had more than one "variable" value, the plot and the legend should match, but all points would still be filled with white. If you provide  test data then I could test it.